Predicting future states in hidden Markov models -- use the Viterbi algorithm?
The Viterbi algorithm is used to decode hidden states in hidden Markov models (HMMs) by working out which sequence of states is most likely. To do this, it first identifies which state $j \in \{1, ..., K\}$ was most likely to give rise to state $k \in \{1, ..., K\}$ at each time point $t$, and then reconstructs the sequence by working backwards through the sequence. This requires an estimate of the (log) probability density of each state at each time point, given the HMM's parameters.
I've searched, by struggled, to find information about making predictions of future states in HMMs after implementing the Viterbi algorithm on training data. For instance, if we have $T$ training data points, what's the best possible action for predicting the state at time point $T + 1$. If we have out-of-sample data, we could enter that into the Viterbi algorithm too, but that seems like cheating -- we would be using the (log) probability density of the future data, given the HMM's parameter estimates. The other approach is just to use the transition matrix of the HMM to sample a new state at time $T + 1$ given we were in state $k$ at time $T$. However, this doesn't seem to be in the spirit on the Viterbi algorithm of finding the most likely sequence.
Does anyone have any advice or insight into this problem?
